# Get PID of the signal sender in C

Tags: c, signals

I've been searching for a way to return the PID of the signal sender's process. Here's my code:

```c
void    get_pid(int sig, siginfo_t *info, void *context)
{
    printf("PID of signal sender = %d\n", info->si_pid);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct sigaction    sa;
    
    printf("PID: %d\n", getpid());      //display PID for kill()
    sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sa.sa_sigaction = get_pid;
    sigaction(SIGUSR1, &sa, NULL);
    pause();                            //wait for a signal
}
```

This program first displays its PID so another program can use `kill()` to send it a signal. Then it calls `pause()` so the program doesn't end before it gets a signal.

How can I access the sender's PID from the main function?

Comment: My god format that code, please!

Comment: Never use `printf()` in signal handler.

Comment: `getpid` and `get_pid` are different identifiers.

Comment: @liliscent It is fine to use `printf` in a signal handler if normal control flow is guaranteed to be blocked on `pause` or `sigsuspend` when the signal is delivered.  OP can use `sigprocmask` together with `sigsuspend` to ensure this.

Comment: liliscent, i understand but it's actually just for a test, i wanted to return the pid to the main but i can't even do that so i just put a printf() even if it's going to display some non ASCII characters

Comment: @zwol How are you going to guarantee that a process is in `pause()` when it receives a signal.

Comment: well thx Downvoter, it's was why it didn't works, now it does XD

Comment: @JeremyP You can't actually guarantee that; that's why `sigsuspend` exists (it atomically unblocks some signals while sleeping).  But for a test program like this `pause` is fine; the "correct" approach would double the length of `main`.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile cleanly - did you forget to `#include` some headers?

Answer (score 9):

So problems with your code:

1. your sigaction is `getpid()` not `get_pid()`. [getpid](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpid.2.html) is an existing library function.
2. Do not call `printf` in a signal handler. It's not signal safe.

The proper way to do this would be just to set a variable in the handler and print it in `main`

```
static volatile int signalPid = -1;
void    get_pid(int sig, siginfo_t *info, void *context)
{
    signalPid = info->si_pid;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct sigaction        sa;

    printf("PID: %d\n", getpid());       //display PID for kill()
    sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sa.sa_sigaction = get_pid;
    sigaction(SIGUSR1, &sa, NULL);
    pause();                           //wait for a signal
    printf("PID of signal sender = %d\n", signalPid);
}
```

Once you are calling the correct signal handler, it should work.

Comment: As for the question how to safely inform the main program execution that a signal arrived. You can use the self-pipe-trick for that. Open a `pipe(2)` and write a signal handler which writes the `siginfo_t` data into the pipe. You can select or poll on the reading end of the pipe to see if a signal happened, and if so read out the information from there.

Comment: @JeremyP Thx for the first two advices, though, where should i set this integer you call "signalPID" ?

Comment: That's awfully complex, @datenwolf — the `pause()` won't return until it gerts a signal, so the printing can be done immediately after `pause()` and before exiting from `main()`.

Comment: @AyfaiseAyfaise `signalPid` is just a variable with global or static scope. I initialsie it to -1 and then set it to the pid in the signal handler.

Comment: @JeremyP do i really have to use a global / static variable ? This is a college project and the teachers doesn't really appreciate them except if i have no other choice

Comment: @AyfaiseAyfaise You have no choice in this case except by using the `pipe()` method of datenwolf but if you are just trying to get it to work at all, using a variable is the light weight answer.

Comment: Doesn't that need to be `static volatile int signalPid;`?  That still won't make updates to  `signalPid` atomic, but I'm assuming `pause()` will hide that.  See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2016.html

Comment: @AndrewHenle It probably should be volatile, thinking about it. Otherwise the optimiser might choose to replace the reference to it in the `printf` to a constant `-1`.

Comment: It does need to be `volatile`, or the compiler is entitled to generate code that doesn't notice it has changed after `pause` returns. In fact, it needs to be `static volatile sig_atomic_t` or technically it's UB to write to it _at all_ -- and moreover `sig_atomic_t` may not be big enough to hold a PID -- but, again, because the main thread of execution is blocked on `pause` when the signal arrives, it's fine, _and so is calling `printf` directly from the signal handler_.

Comment: @zwol In this case there is only one thread so we probably get away without making it atomic.

Comment: ..or just signal a semaphore.upon which the main thread is waiting.

Comment: @JeremyP Probably, yes.

Comment: Note that the C standard is excruciatingly rigid about what can be done inside a signal handler, but POSIX relaxes the rules very considerably. Roughly, in standard C, you can reset the signal handler for the handled signal, modify global variables of type `volatile sig_atomic_t`, and either return or call some of the process exit functions, and that's about it. In POSIX, there are many more functions that can be called and variables that, but care is needed. You must decide which standard is relevant. Given the question, POSIX is relevant and standard C is not — standard C doesn't have PIDs.